# How to make the slide down animation using css3 with display none to block

Tags: html, css

I was just wondering how could i add `display: none` and `display: block` to my animation with a ease effect.

**HTML**

```
<div class="floating-vociebox">
  <a>New updates</a>
</div>
```

Any help would be appreciated

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/57ukw5cp/)**

Comment: Explain the effect and our could help you.

Comment: @MattewDeveloper as you see the voice box will slide in from the top i do need the same effect with the voice box should be `display: none` initially

Comment: `display` CANNOT BE ANIMATED. You can use `opacity` if you want it to fade in/ out.

Comment: I agree @Aloso but I still think we can animate using keyframes.

Comment: @Benjamin Please explain again. [On this page](https://jsfiddle.net/glebkema/yfmptmn1/) you can see three kinds of animation. What kind do you need?

Comment: How would animating `display` look like? `none` -> `bone` -> `blne` -> `bloe` -> `bloc` -> `block` xD

Comment: @GlebKemarsky before the animation starts the display property should be none once the animation starts the display should be block and I should see the slide down animation

Answer (score 1):

I have tried to start from `display:none;`. I have three variants to add movement and fade-in by CSS3 and jQuery. Which one is more like what you need?

```js
$( document ).ready(function(){
 $('.variant-1').fadeIn( 3000 ).addClass('animate-1');
 
  $('.variant-2').css('display','block').delay( 0 ).queue(function(){
    $(this).addClass('animate-2').dequeue();
  });
 
  $('.variant-3').addClass('visible').delay( 0 ).queue(function(){
    $(this).addClass('animate-2').dequeue();
  });
});
```

```css
.floating-vociebox {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 120px;
  height: 30px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
  border-radius: 4px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 100px;
  transform: translateY(-90px);
  display: none;
}
.variant-1 {
  left: 10px;
  transition: background-color 0.3s, transform 3s ease-in-out;
}
.variant-2 {
  left: 150px;
}
.variant-3 {
  left: 290px;
}
.variant-2, 
.variant-3 {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: background-color 0.3s, opacity 3s ease-in, transform 3s ease-in-out;
}
.visible {
  display: block;
}
.animate-1 {
  transform: translateY(0);
}
.animate-2 {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateY(0);
}
.floating-vociebox:hover {
  background-color: darkblue;
}
.floating-vociebox a {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 30px;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="floating-vociebox variant-1">
  <a>Variant 1</a>
</div>
<div class="floating-vociebox variant-2">
  <a>Variant 2</a>
</div>
<div class="floating-vociebox variant-3">
  <a>Variant 3</a>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/glebkema/gcg7f4pj/